# header file ~synatx error(asking for a parantheses)

Tags: c++, syntax, circular-dependency

i'm having the fallowing header file. I get this error: `expected ')' before 'A'` why is this?
I tried to rewrite and to replace... i`m out of ideas and i dont know what may be the root of the problem...

```
#ifndef UICONSOLE_H_
#define UICONSOLE_H_

#include "Catalog.h"

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class UIconsole{ 
public:
    UIconsole(Catalog A); // error here.
    void runUI();

private:
    void showMenu();
    string getString();
    int getOption();

    void addStudent();
    void removeStudent();
    void editStudent();
    void printStudent();
    void printAllStudents();


    void addAssignment();
    void removeAssignment();
    void editAssignment();
    void printAssignment();
    void printAllAssignment();

    void printAllUnder5();
    void sortAlphabetically();
    void searchById();
};
#endif /* UICONSOLE_H_ */
```

edit, with the content of a dependency header:

```
#ifndef CATALOG_H_
#define CATALOG_H_
#include <string>

#include "UIconsole.h"
#include "Catalog.h"

#include "StudentRepository.h"
#include "StudentValidator.h"

using namespace std;

class Catalog{
private:
    StudentRepository studRepo;
    StudentValidator studValid;

public:
    Catalog(StudentRepository stre, StudentValidator stva):studRepo(stre),studValid(stva){};
    void addNewStudent(string name, int id, int group);
    void removeStudent(string name);
    void editStudent(int name, int id, int group);
    Student seachStudent(string name);
};

#endif /* CATALOG_H_ */
```

Comment: Can you also show the content of Catalog.h

Comment: `Catalog.h` doesn't appear to be doing what you expect - you're getting the error because the compiler hasn't seen a declaration for `Catalog` yet.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I feel you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Catalog.h` file has a couple of unnecessary `#include` directives:

```
#include "UIconsole.h"
#include "Catalog.h"
```

Get rid of these from the particular file.

The `#include "Catalog.h"` is unnecessary, but harmless (because of the include guards).  However, the `#include "UIconsole.h"` causes the declaration of `class UIconsole` to be processed before the declaration of `class Catalog`.  So when the compiler hits the

```
UIconsole(Catalog A);
```

line it still has no idea what `Catalog` is.

Another thing that's unrelated to this problem but should be fixed is the

```
using namespace std;
```

directives in the header files.  That's a bad practice that should be avoided - in header files you should generally specify the full name of types in the `std` namespace:

```
void addNewStudent(std::string name, int id, int group);
void removeStudent(std::string name);
```

Forcing a namespace into the global namespace on all users of a header can cause problems when there's a name conflict (essentially, you're removing the ability for users to control name conflicts with namespaces if you force the directive on them).

Comment: Yes it fixed... haven't seen the include of `Catalog.h` in `Catalog.h`... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular include: Catalog includes Console, which in turn includes catalog again. Now the safeguard prevent the infinite include, but it does not magically solve the problem.

Lets assume that in your case, Catalog is included first:

The compiler does:

- include Catalog. h
- include Console.h
- Include Catalog.h but actually skip the content because of the safeguard.
- continue with processing Console.h but it has not seen the Catalog class yet.

You need to solve the circular include. One way would be to put a pointer instead of an object Catalog and have a forward declaration. Or you can simply remove the include UIconsole.h from Catalog.h, as it does not seem to be needed in the header.